# Criação de uma tabela de conversão de graus Fahrenheit para Celsius

Tags: java, formatação

Escreva um programa que dadas duas temperaturas em graus Fahrenheit (valores inteiros) produz uma tabela com todos os valores nesse intervalo intervalados de meio grau Fahrenheit. Por exemplo, a execução do programa para os valores 30 e 35 deve produzir o seguinte *output*:

Indique valores do intervalo separados por espaço (min max):

30

35

Fahrenheit Celsius

30.00 -1.11

30.50 -0.83

31.00 -0.56

31.50 -0.28

32.00 0.00

32.50 0.28

33.00 0.56

33.50 0.83

34.00 1.11

34.50 1.39

35.00 1.67

E deixo aí o meu código,não sei se conseguem perceber o raciocínio que tentei ter mas também é complicado pois ainda tenho bastantes dúvidas na utilização do laço for.Quando tento correr esse código o programa pede os valores minemos e máximos, mas depois de eu inserir o máximo o programa dá o erro:

> java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System . out . println("Por favor indique um valor minimo:");
    int min = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Agora indique um valor máximo:");
    int max = scanner.nextInt();
    double celsius = (min-32*(5/9));
    int i = 0;
    min++;


    for (i=0; max + 1 > min;min++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%6.2f\t\t%6.2f\n","Fahrenheit" + min + " Celsius " + celsius);
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Tem vários erros, alguns talvez porque falte parte do código.

Se vai calcular dados com parte decimal precisa usar pelo menos um `float`, não pode ser um inteiro.

Se o cálculo precisa ser feito em cada linha da tabela a fórmula do cálculo precisa estar dentro do laço para repetir cada vez.

E deve fazer com a variável do laço que vai incrementando. Alias quem deve incrementar é a variável de controle do laço e não o mínimo. O mínimo deve ser usado para inicializá-la. O incremento deve ser de `0.5` conforme mostra o enunciado. A condição de saída também estava errada, a variável de controle que deve ir até o máximo.

A formatação do texto também está errada. Veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) como usar.

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Por favor indique um valor minimo:");
        float min = scanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Agora indique um valor máximo:");
        float max = scanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.printf("Fahrenheit Celsius\n");
        for (float i = min; i <= max; i += .5) {
            System.out.printf("%6.2f     %6.2f%n", i, ((i - 32.0) * ( 5.0 / 9.0)));
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GhBj23). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ghlgddiw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/TemperatureConversion.java).